# Any Public API for IRCTC to check PNR Status and Seat Availability?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on an Android application to check PNR status and seat availability. So is there any public API for getting this information?

I tried many API, but most of them are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://rapidapi.com/IRCTCAPI/api/irctc1 ?

They have some sample examples also,

```
const axios = require("axios");

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://irctc1.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/getPNRStatus',
  params: {pnrNumber: 'xxxxxxxxxx'},
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'irctc1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'YOUR KEY'
 }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
console.error(error);
});
```

> Note please use your key in **X-RapidAPI-Key**

Apart from PNR and Seat availability they some more useful API's.